# Transform an XML by grouping the fields

Tags: xslt

My knowledge to XSLT is limited but always eager to learn. I am  currently working on a template that requires to transform the XML input. I've been trying to group the InvoiceNum fields and not getting anywhere. 
I am getting an error: Envision.Utilities.XsltEngine-Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's the input XML for reference:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
  <Request>
  <Information>
    <ImageID>987456321</ImageID>
    <Contract>123456789</Contract>
    <Lastname>MICKEYMOUSE</Lastname>
  </Information>
<Document>
    <InvoiceNum>123456823</InvoiceNum>
    <Reference>AD20985224</Reference>
    <InvoiceNum>100000123</InvoiceNum>
    <Reference>AS20101387</Reference>
    <InvoiceNum>858511825</InvoiceNum>
    <Reference>GF96844</Reference>
    <InvoiceNum>885154145</InvoiceNum>
    <Reference>FGFD2018</Reference>
    <InvoiceNum>25241111</InvoiceNum>
    <Reference>SD88888</Reference>
    <InvoiceNum>8571414</InvoiceNum>
    <Reference>DF864841254</Reference>
    </Document>
 </Request>
```

Here's my XSLT format for reference:
What am I missing? Is there better way to format the XSLT template I have currently below? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:param name="cols" select="3" />

<xsl:template match="Request">
 <table border="1">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="InvoiceNum[position() mod $cols = 1]"/>
 </table>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Document">
<xsl:variable name="group" select=". | following-sibling::InvoiceNum
[position() &lt; $cols]" />
<xsl:for-each select="*">
<xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
<Invoice>
<InvoiceNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="InvoiceNum()"/>
</InvoiceNumber>
 <xsl:for-each select="$group">
 <xsl:value-of select="*[$i]"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </Invoice>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the XML output I'd like to have:

```
<InvCase>
  <Invoices>
    <InvoicemNumber>InvoiceNum1</InvoicemNumber>
    <InvoicemNumber>InvoiceNum2</InvoicemNumber>
    <InvoicemNumber>InvoiceNum3</InvoicemNumber>
 </Invoices>
</InvCase>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to group in the `InvoiceNum` into groups of 3. The first issue you have is that in your template matching `Request` you do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="InvoiceNum[position() mod $cols = 1]"/>
```

But `InvoiceNum` is not a child of `Request`, and so that selects nothing. You probably need to do this...

Additionally, you have a template matching `Document`, but this probably needs to match `InvoiceNum` (Doing `following-sibling::InvoiceNum` would not return anything if you were matching `Document` as the `InvoiceNum` elements are children of `Document` not following siblings).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:param name="cols" select="3" />

<xsl:template match="Request">
 <InvCases>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Document/InvoiceNum[position() mod $cols = 1]"/>
 </InvCases>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="InvoiceNum">
  <xsl:variable name="group" select=". | following-sibling::InvoiceNum[position() &lt; $cols]" />
  <Invoice>
   <xsl:for-each select="$group">
    <InvoiceNumber>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </InvoiceNumber>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Invoice>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for explaining one by one. That helped! I tried to execute the Xslt and I'm getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "....Trying to search what needs to remove or add.

Comment: I suspect that error is not due to the XSLT itself, but how you are applying the XSLT to the XML or how to you try to process the output. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMk for an example of the XSLT itself in action.

Comment: I am trying to transform the input XML to group all the <InvoiceNum>  under the <Invoices> tag.  Let's say the XML input has a total of 6 or 10 <InvoiceNum>  fields. Then the final XML output should have all the 6 or 10 <InvoicemNumber> tags with different <InvoiceNum> value for each fields.

Comment: Tim here's the rest of my XSLT template and I am stuck on how to populate and group all the <InvoiceNum> and populate it under multiple <InvoiceNumber>

Comment: Tim here's the rest of my XSLT template and I am stuck on how to populate and group all the <InvoiceNum> 
and populate it under multiple <InvoiceNumber> tags

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- match the root node -->
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/Request"/>
 </xsl:template> 
 <xsl:template match="Request">
 <xsl:template match="Request">
    <xsl:element name="User">
  <xsl:value-of select="Racf"/>
    </xsl:element>

Comment: </xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="InvCase">                   
  <xsl:element name="Invocies">                     
   <xsl:element name="InvoiceNumber">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Document/InvoiceNum[position() mod $cols = 1]"/>
   <xsl:variable name="group" select=". | following-sibling::InvoiceNum[position() &lt; $c
   <xsl:for-each select="$group">                                   
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>       
   </xsl:element>     
 </xsl:element>     
   </xsl:element>            
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: You should really edit your question with this information, as code is hard to read in comments. Also, ensure the expected output you show corresponds directly with the input you have provided. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Tim for the quick response. I found the other way to group the <InvoiceNum> for the Input XML and did an <xsl:copy-of select= " "/> in the XLST.